# Handling device motion in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm creating a app which is similar to car race, where i need to know how can i move a uiview when i slightly turn ipad. i.e, if i turn ipad right side the view has to move right side based on device motion. I have used,

```
 -(void) motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
if(event.subtype==UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
{
    // Code at shake event

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Motion" message:@"Phone Vibrate"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];


}
}
```

To find when a device is shaked. I need to know when i'm turning ipad slightly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
-(BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {

return YES;

}

 -(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
 {

   if(event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)            
  {

    // YOUR STUFF

  }

}
```

just write the above code for shake gesture to work...

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy Coding...!!!